# Negative margins and CSS filters

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a div behind another div on my websites layout.
I cannot use "position:absolute", so I went so negative margins.
Everything went right, until I added my filters.

That's the div with the background image I want to put behind the main content.

```
.tshowcase-background-profile {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
     filter: blur(5px);
     background-image:url('MY IMAGE');
     background-size:cover;
     z-index: -50;
}
```

If I delete all the filters, it works fine. The div is below the other div with the content in it. But as soon as I apply filters to it, it goes on top of the div with the content.

I can check and uncheck the filter line in Google Chrome Inspector, and it really change from below the content to over the content...and so on.

Why is that?

I need to put a div behind my content with a blurred background, but cannot use Absolute position.

Thanks

EDIT : [JSFiddle Example of my issue](https://jsfiddle.net/ty2jdt81/)
. Try deleting the filters, and click "RUN", you'll see that the Youtube icon will appear on top of the DIV, and below if filters are on.

Comment: could you add a fiddle illustration the issue? related: creating a [mcve]

Comment: Sure! Added in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `position: relative`?

https://jsfiddle.net/3v8a6qmy/

Comment: Wow I can't believe I haven't thought of that earlier. Thanks a lot Johannes! It's working :)